# Minimum difference between $2^n$ and $3^m$ vs. $N$ where $N=n+m$

Tags: number-theory, collatz-conjecture

I'd like to know minimum difference $D$ as a function of $N$ where:

$D=|2^n-3^m|$

$N=n+m$

Just experimentally, it looks like $\ln D$ is linear with $N$, approximately:

$\ln{D}\approx0.425N$

[image]

For a given $N$, the minimum $D$ occurs at $n=\lfloor{N\over{1+{\log2\over{\log3}}}}\rfloor+1$ if $2^n-3^m$ is positive and $n=\lfloor{N\over{1+{\log2\over{\log3}}}}\rfloor$ if $2^n-3^m$ is negative.

A detail:

[image]

The red dots are where the minimum $2^n-3^m$ is negative, blue positive.

So there's slight amount of "noise" around that line so maybe an exact expression is unlikely, but is there a more formal way to derive this?

Comment: Are $N,n,m$ integers? Non-negative integers?

Comment: $D = min( 2^{\lceil N \frac{\ln 3}{\ln 2+\ln 3} \rceil}-3^{N-\lceil N \frac{\ln 3}{\ln 2+\ln 3} \rceil},3^{N-\lfloor N \frac{\ln 3}{\ln 2+\ln 3} \rfloor }-2^{\lfloor N \frac{\ln 3}{\ln 2+\ln 3} \rfloor } )$ for every $N\geq 1$ gives minimum value for $D$ so $\ln D$ have a formula, the catch is this formula is hard to evaluate.

Comment: @Xpw -- $N,m,n \in \mathbb Z$

Comment: @Ahmad I tested this for all values of $N$ up to 100: $D=2^{k}-3^{N-k}$ where $k=\text{round}\left(\frac{N-4}{1+\frac{\ln 2}{\ln 3}}+2.5\right)=\left\lceil\frac{N-4}{1+\frac{\ln 2}{\ln 3}}+2\right\rceil$

Comment: I've done a great deal experimentally on this question. For one of the compilations of results see http://go.helms-net.de/math/collatz/2hochS_3hochN_V2.htm

Comment: @Gottfried -- very nice, thanks.

Comment: @JoeKnapp why did you tag this Collatz?

Comment: @Frost if there is a Collatz cycle of length $L=n+m$ where there are $n$ even iterates and $m$ odd iterates, then ${2^n}\approx{3^m}$, as the steps down must be commensurate with the steps up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $2^a = 3^b \iff a\ln 2 = b\ln 3$, under the constraint that $\nu + \mu = N$ we have $2^{\nu} = 3^{\mu}$ for $\nu = \frac{\ln 3}{\ln 6}N$ and $\mu = \frac{\ln 2}{\ln 6}N$. The smallest distance $\lvert 2^n - 3^m\rvert$ for $m,n$ integers with $n + m = N$ therefore occurs when $n = \lfloor \nu\rfloor$ or $n = \lceil \nu\rceil$. Writing $\delta = n - \nu$, we thus have $-1 < \delta < 1$ and

$$D = \lvert 2^n - 3^m\rvert = \lvert 2^{\nu + \delta} - 3^{\mu - \delta}\rvert = \exp \biggl( \frac{(\ln 2)(\ln 3)}{\ln 6}N\biggr)\cdot \lvert 2^{\delta} - 3^{-\delta}\rvert.$$

Thus

$$\ln D = \frac{(\ln 2)(\ln 3)}{\ln 6}N + \ln \lvert 2^{\delta} - 3^{-\delta}\rvert.$$

Since $C := \frac{(\ln 2)(\ln 3)}{\ln 6} \approx 0.4250012479336228$, the first term corresponds to your straight line, and that the exact values are close to that line is equivalent to $\delta$ not being too close to $0$. The inequality $\lvert \delta\rvert < 1$ implies $\lvert 2^{\delta} - 3^{-\delta}\rvert < 3^1 - 2^{-1} = \frac{5}{2}$, so $\ln D$ can never be much above that line. But $\delta$ can sometimes be very close to $0$. If $N$ is the denominator of a convergent of $\frac{\ln 3}{\ln 6}$, then

$$\biggl\lvert \frac{\ln 3}{\ln 6} - \frac{K}{N}\biggr\rvert < \frac{1}{N^2},$$

so $\lvert \nu - K\rvert < \frac{1}{N}$, hence $\lvert\delta\rvert < \frac{1}{N}$, and then

$$2^{\delta} - 3^{-\delta} = \exp(\delta\ln 2) - \exp (-\delta\ln 3) = \delta\ln 6 + O(\delta^2),$$

whence $\ln D \approx C\cdot N + \ln \delta < C\cdot N - \ln N$ in that case.

Of course a difference of $\approx \ln N$ is still small relative to $C\cdot N$. However, depending on the irrationality measure of $\frac{\ln 3}{\ln 6}$, there may be convergents where $\frac{K}{N}$ is much closer than $\frac{1}{N^2}$. If the irrationality measure is finite - and that's overwhelmingly likely - then the distance is bounded below by a power of $N$, and then we have $\lvert CN - \ln D\rvert \in O(\ln N)$. But if the irrationality measure is infinite, then $\lvert CN - \ln D\rvert$ can be of larger order than $\ln N$.

Comment: Perfect! thanks. Interesting predictions about $\delta$ and deviations from the line. I'll look into that.