# How to compute an "effectively computable constant" in a formula of approximation of powers of $2$ and $3$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-approximation, collatz-conjecture, transcendence-theory

In [his blog](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2011/08/21/hilberts-seventh-problem-and-powers-of-2-and-3/) Terence Tao discusses the distance between powers of 2 and 3 and presents the following corollary:

---

***Corollary 4*** (Separation between powers of {2} and powers of {3})

- For any positive integers {p, q} one has

  $$   \displaystyle |3^p - 2^q| \geq \frac{c}{q^C} 3^p$$

  for some effectively computable constants {c, C > 0} (which may be slightly
  different from those in Proposition 3).

---

What does he mean with "... effectively computable constants ... " ?

I've only a guess so far based on the inspection of the curve for $p$ and $q$ *(=$N$ and $S$ in my usual notational style)* using $p$ from the first hundred or so of the convergents of the continued fraction of $\log_2 (3)$ giving data for $p$ up to $1e175$ (only convergents where $2^q > 3^p$ are used).

From this I guess for instance $c=0.005$ and $C=1.01$. But those guesses might be much too crude.
*I already presented an older guess in a [MO-answer of mine](https://mathoverflow.net/a/278187/7710) but which seems even cruder.*

So my question:

> ***Q:*** How can one compute that constants?

---

pictures making my guess. Used only that cases where $2^S > 3^N > 2^{S-1}$ that means also from the original convergents of the continued fractions only each second one.

Image for the whole tested interval:
[image: pic1]

Detail for the smaller leading interval:
[image: pic2]

Detail for the smaller critical interval at $N \approx 1e166$:
[image: pic3]

Picture rotated to make comparision better visible. Note that the labeling of the axes are now no more correct, and the apparent numbers $N$ are scaled due to rotation (note: the logs of all values were rotated using $\cos(),\sin()$ by $45$ deg).
[image: pic4]

Comment: I'm assuming... by reading the proof of this Proposition 3 (or, rather, of Baker’s theorem of which it is a corollary), that presumably is proven in not only a constructive way, but by describing algorithmically how to obtain these constants.

Comment: @ClementC.- yes, this might be. But in any case: I'd like *to see* such a constructive computation or algorithm. I've come across such phrase "is effectively computable" frequently in the last weeks, but never found such computation been described - perhaps I'm missing some basic understanding here.

Comment: Well, have you had a look at the proof in question?

Comment: @ClementC.:Hmm, I've read that blog-entry many times (not only this week) and never found any thing what would show me how I could actually *do* that "effective computation". Perhaps there's some blind spot on my side...

Comment: Oh, I am talking about the proof of Baker’s theorem... I don't know it, but as far as I can see it's not in that blog post.

Comment: @clementc: ah, you suggest that such a description for the actual computation-method might be found in the paper which contains Baker's theorem and proof...

Comment: Yes --  the blog post suggests the original proof is constructive and algorithmic.

Comment: @ClementC: ah well, I'll see... surprising that the values of that constants $c$ and $C$ are not very common and frequently documented - in sight of the frequent discussions of that problem of powers of 3 and 2. But I'll take your hint and try to see what I can find from that Baker's paper. Thanks for the hint so far.

Comment: @GottfriedHelms in his blog does Terrence Tao discuss the relation between this and the Collatz conjecture? Or Mahler's 3/2 problem?

Comment: @RobertFrost: yes, indeed he does (there are related two pages in his blog), but no explicte values for $c$ nor for $C$ is given

Comment: @GottfriedHelms I have long thought this is the beating heart of the problem. I must see what he has written when I get a chance. There is a recent post on here which is related.

Comment: @GottfriedHelms here's the post (with a good answer) which looks on the face of it related to yours but I haven't had chance to study your question in detail: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2398152/

Answer (score 1):

A method for computing the constants arising from linear forms of logarithms is clearly summarized [here](http://www.math.leidenuniv.nl/~evertse/dio2011-linforms.pdf).

For the case where there are two logarithms, one can appeal to the results of Laurent, Mignotte, and Nesterenko for sharper constants (for references, see Exercise 4 from above, and see my [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2727101/perigee-apogee-upper-bounds-from-belaga-and-mignotte)).

**Update 4/18/2018:**  One should also consider the work of Matveev (found in the references above) and G. Rhin ("Approximants de Padé et mesures effective s d'irrationalité").

Comment: Oh, thank you for the link. Unfortunately I haven't been able to go through this article of H-J- Evertsen a couple of years ago - I've got lost in space, so to say... Just recently I looked again at J. Simons papers on the disproof of the m-cycles in the Collatz-problem and took on to chew through the arguments around the result of G. Rhin - at least I seem to have understood this correctly (I showed my efforts in http://go.helms-net.de/math/collatz/Collatz_1cycledisproof.pdf for its open discussion of correctness) and so I think I have at least a glance of what is going on ... ;-)

Comment: @GottfriedHelms  Thanks for the references!