# Perigee, Apogee Upper Bounds from Belaga and Mignotte

Tags: number-theory, collatz-conjecture

I am currently reading the work of [Belaga](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/2329216_Effective_Polynomial_Upper_Bounds_to_Perigees_and_Numbers_of_3xd-Cycles_of_a_Given_Oddlength) on upper bounds on minimal cyclic iterates in the $3x+d$ problem.

In the paper,  the  author gives an upper bound on the perigee as
$$
 dk^{C_2}
$$
   where $k$ is the number of odd elements in the cycle, and $C_2$ is an effectively computable constant not exceeding $32$ (as per Corollary 2 in the cited paper of [Laurent et al](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022314X85711419)).

Later in the introduction, Belaga mentions an upper bound for the apogee (maximal element)

$$dk^C (3/2)^k $$

(the author and Mignotte derive this upper bound in [another paper](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.em/1048515662) )

> **Question**:  Does 32 still apply as an upper bound for the effectively computable constant C (when bounding the apogee)?

The author writes that he corresponded with another author in the derivation of this constant (for the perigee).

Comment: Hmm, empirically, $C_2$ seems to be around $2$ from own heuristical computations (a short list is in my entry https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2886523/1714 ), but that -although much suggestive- does of course not provide a proof...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can apply the [results of Rhin](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022314X86900363) (as provided by Lemma 12 in the [work of Simons and De Weger](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.59.5358&rep=rep1&type=pdf)) to derive sharp constants.

Assume $k+l>k$.  Lemma 12 in Simons/De Weger demonstrates the inequality

$$ (k+l)\log 2 - k\log 3 > e^{-13.3(0.46507)}k^{-13.3}.$$  This inequality provides means for deriving a lower bound on the denominator $2^{k+l}-3^{k}$ of a periodic orbit element; the argument in the abovementioned paper of Belaga/Mignotte demonstrates how this lower bound can be applied to derive an upper bound on the maximal iterate element.

Comment: One problem I still have with this nice formula is that I didn't see a route, ***how*** these constant are derived (at least as a general idea, understandable by an amateur) . [Of course it is nice to have such nice constants already at hands :-) ( +1 for the application here)]